# Change Model Property Value through AJAX Call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a table of data I want to change when clicked is triggered, and my data is wrapped in the initial model value (List). When I tried calling it responds with an error

> POST https://localhost:7230/controller/List 404

**My Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> List()
    {
        //Call the repo to get data
        var blogPosts = await blogPostRepository.GetAllAsync();

        return View(blogPosts);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> List(string sampType)
    {
        //Call the repo to get data
        var blogPosts = await blogPostRepository.GetAllAsync();

        if (sampType == "goku")
        {
            var gokuBlog = blogPosts.Where(x => x.Heading == "Goku");
            return View(gokuBlog);
        }

        return View(blogPosts);
    }
```

**My Javascript**

```
$("#updateBtn").click(function () {

$.post('/AdminBlog/List', { sampType: "goku" });
});
```

**Here's the html table I want to update**

```
   @if(Model != null && Model.Any())
{
    <button id="updateBtn" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Update</button>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id</td>
                    <td>Heading</td>
                    <td>Tags</td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var blogPost in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@blogPost.Id</td>
                        <td>@blogPost.Heading</td>
                        <td>
                           <div class="d-flex">
                                @foreach (var tag in blogPost.Tags)
                                {
                                    <span class="badge bg-secondary me-2">@tag.Name</span>
                                }
                            </div>   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-area =""
                               asp-controller="AdminBlogPost" 
                               asp-action="Edit"
                               asp-route-id="@blogPost.Id">
                               Edit
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at List post ? Can you get the value of sampType?

Comment: Tried it now, and it never reaches my controller action even though my URL link is fine

Comment: Can you get the table in the list view? What's your get request url ?

Comment: Besides, you can use `F12` to see if any error messages in the console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a patialview to show changed model property value,below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

1.Create the _PatialList.cshtml:

```
<table id="p" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Heading</td>
            <td>Tags</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var blogPost in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@blogPost.Id</td>
                <td>@blogPost.Heading</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        @foreach (var tag in blogPost.Tags)
                        {
                            <span class="badge bg-secondary me-2">@tag.Name</span>
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-area=""
                       asp-controller="AdminBlogPost"
                       asp-action="Edit"
                       asp-route-id="@blogPost.Id">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2.In Post List action change like below:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> List(string sampType)
    {
        //Call the repo to get data
        var blogPosts = await blogPostRepository.GetAllAsync();

        if (sampType == "goku")
        {
            var gokuBlog = blogPosts.Where(x => x.Heading == "Goku");
            //return View(gokuBlog);
            return PartialView("_PatialList", gokuBlog);
        }

        return View(blogPosts);
    }
```

3. Add id to the  html table like:`<table id="p" class="table">`

4.Then add a function in your ajax to show the data,:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$("#updateBtn").click(function () {

$.post('/AdminBlog/List', { sampType: "goku" }, function (data) {
            $('#p').html(data);
        });
});
```

result:

[image]